# ZF2 Breadcrumbs with dynamic content

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-navigation

How can I create breadcrumbs with dynamic content in ZF2 using Zend Navigation and the Breadcrumbs view helper?  For example:

Home -> People -> John Doe

In this case "John Doe" is the profile page you are currently viewing which is loaded with a uri like /people/23424 where the last parameter is the id of the person (there could be thousands).

How can I do this given that all the navigation pages are created in the service config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add nav to your service config:

```
'navigation' => function($sm) {
    $navigation = new \Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
    $navigation = $navigation->createService($sm);
    /**
     * Do extra work here with the nav at instantiate time..
     */ 
 },
```

or more simply:

```
'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
```

Now you can fetch the items you want to change like this:

```
$nav = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
$page = $nav->findByLabel('My Label');
$page->setLabel('New Label');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a session and store the breadcrumbs there. You'd probably want to limit yourself to say 10 pages though.